# Join command not showing a desired outcome

Tags: bash, shell

There are two text files in a comma-sepearted version. The first file contains 'student number,first name' and the second file contains 'first name,grade'. I need to sort a common field and join them together so that I can see all remaining fields except the common field from both files in one output.

**INPUT FILE 1:**

1001,james

1020,shawn

1030,peter

1040,lisa

**INPUT FILE 2:**

james,80

peter,65

lisa,90

In this case, the common field is 'first name' and the output should generate 'their student number,grade' format.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

1001,80

1040,90

1030,65

1020,0

```
sort -b -t $',' -k 2b,2 $1 > file1_sorted.txt
sort -b -t $',' -k 1b,1 $2 > file2_sorted.txt
join -1 2 -2 1 -t $',' -o 1.1,2.2 -a 1 file1_sorted.txt file2_sorted.txt
```

This is what my code looks like but it doesn't give me any outcome and error message. Can you help me figure out what's causing the problem here?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU sort:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,2.2 -a 1 -e 0 <(sort -t, -k2 file1) <(sort -t, file2)
```

Output:

```
1001,80
1040,90
1030,65
1020,0
```